# How can I call a rest service while processing another rest service in the reactive paradigm?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to wrap my head around reactive programming and the spring webflux library so I wanted to try something first with WebClient so I found the RESTful pokemon api (https://pokeapi.co/) and started playing around with it, but I'm having some trouble trying to call a second rest service from the information returned from the first service I call, as I don't get any result back from the nested call

I've been reading the reactor library and looked around for operators that could help me with what I need, but I must be either missing or misunderstanding something as I can't really find examples even if it seems like a common scenario, I'm trying to use `flatMap` to keep my object wrapped in a single `Mono`, and use other operators to print the information, also tried to use `block()` but I get the same result.

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import lombok.val;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class PokemonClient {

    WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/");

    public void getPokemon() {
        val result = client.get()
                .uri("/pokemon/ditto")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange();

        Mono<Species> pkmnMono = result.flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Pokemon.class))
                .map(pokemon -> pokemon.getSpecies());

        Mono<Object> resultMono = pkmnMono.flatMap(species -> client.get().uri("/pokemon-species/132/")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Object.class)));

        Object species = resultMono.block();
        System.out.println(species);
    }
}
```

Pokemon and Species are bean classes I only use to map the results from the first call.

I know `client.get().uri("/pokemon-species/132/")`is making it not bring information based on the first call, and that I shouldn't be using `Object`, but at this point I'm just trying to understand what's going on, my original approach calls `species.getUrl()` ,

I expected it to bring back the information from  `/pokemon-species/132/` but I get nothing, when I try to print it with `pkmnMono.block()` instead, it works with no problem

Comment: So it works when you call block? Reactive streams are lazy - until you subscribe or in your cause block, the stream wont do anything.

Comment: @stacktraceyo No, sorry it was confusing, when i call ```pkmnMono.block()``` (the first request) it works, but when I call ```resultMono.block()``` (the nested request) it does not work.

Comment: what do you mean by that you get nothing? is it null or some error?

Comment: I've just ran your code as it is and get the expected result. Do you use the latest version of Spring?

Comment: @Yossarian nothing really happens, ```System.out.print``` should print the value of ```species``` but nothing gets printed on the console

Comment: @Yossarian I'm running Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and using the io.spring.dependency.management plugin on gradle, is there a newer ver?

Comment: That looks okay. If you're checking the second URL from browser or Postman, does that work?

Comment: @Yossarian seems like you were onto something, what version did you run your code on? I tried to run this on 2.1.6 and 2.1.7, and I get no result, but I ran this on Spring boot 2.1.0 and it works flawlessly, I can't get it to show on postman as I'm not really exposing anything yet, but I'll test around and update, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I used 2.1.7.RELEASE version